# Cognos Report totaling hours over time

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I'm pretty new to Cognos 10 Report Studio so this may be a fairly simple question but I have been unable to find on answer so far.

In my database I have the hours a person has worked in a two week pay period, as well as what month a pay period exists in. I would like to total the over any period of months.

For example a user is prompted to choose a range of time, and they may select a start month of January of some year, and an end date of June of the same or some later year, and then the report would have a column that displays the sum of hours worked by a person between that time frame.

So in essence the sum of hours for every pay period in a given range of dates.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a list (or crosstab) with the User, year, month, and total hours in each month

Create a new data item (maybe something called - Hours by Month) defined as:

```
total([hours] for [Year], [Month], [User])
```

The function allows you to define the scope so the SQL is structured to give you the answer grouped the way you want